# Need to filter and display records using input and select PHP/MySQL only

Tags: php, html, mysql

This database search/filter is part of my website, searching in search works but I've tried a lot of ways to implement searching and filtering by gender as well, but I haven't found a solution yet using only PHP and MYSQL
Here's what I got so far:

```
<?php 
    include("header.php");
    include("config.php");
?>
    

<section id="make_search">
    <div class="search">
        <form action="" method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="search" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['search'])){echo $_GET['search']; } // Gets value and stores it in $_GET['search']?>" class="search_bar" placeholder="Search Records">
            <select name="gender"id="dropdown">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Gender</option>
                <option value="male">Male</option>
                <option value="female">Female</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
            <button type="submit" class="button">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>


<section id="show_records">
        <div class="results">   
            <h2>Click search to view all results.</h2>
            <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Firstname</th>
                        <th>Lastmame</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Message</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                            if(isset($_GET['search']))
                            {   
                                // Define $search_value
                                $search_values = $_GET['search'];
                                $query = "SELECT * FROM uc_messages WHERE CONCAT(First_Name, Last_Name, Gender, Message, Message_Date, Email) LIKE '%$search_values%' ORDER BY 'Last_Name' ASC ";
                                // Runs query and stores it in $query_run
                                $query_run = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query);
                                // If variable matches $search_values it will show records with the relevant information
                                // If not it will says 'No Records Found' and display all records below 
                                if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0) 
                                {
                                    // For every query a subsequent row will be displayed
                                    // Also had an else here if the user doesn't input anything but StackOverflow doesn't want too much code here
                                    foreach($query_run as $row)
                                    {
                                        ?>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td><?php echo $row['First_Name'];?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row['Last_Name'];?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row['Gender'];?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row['Message'];?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row['Message_Date'];?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row['Email'];?></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        ?>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Been searching the internet for hours and can't seem to find a way to filter my records by input and dropdown values. Very new for PHP and my high school hasn't exactly been giving the best learning material and I'm still very new to programming in general. I want to add more select filters eventually but I'm just trying to get the filter working for gender. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even if [you are escaping variables, its not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string%5D)! You should always use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating user provided values into the query.

Comment: Add `AND gender = '{$_POST['gender']}'` (but do it with a placeholder as explained in the above links).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your search request using your search input and the gender option this way !

At first, look at the dataset in my database :

[image]

I use a prepared statement and the POST method.

Here is the form :

```
<section id="make_search">
    <div class="search">
        <form action="#" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="search" value="<?php 
if(isset($_POST['search'])){echo $_POST['search']; }?>" class="search_bar" placeholder="Search Records">
            <select name="gender" id="dropdown">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Gender</option>
                <option value="MALE">MALE</option>
                <option value="FEMALE">FEMALE</option>
                <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
            </select>
            <button type="submit" class="button">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is where I fetch and show datas (inside *tbody*) :

```
<?php
                        if(isset($_POST['search']))
                        {   
                            $search_values = '%' . $_POST['search'] . '%';
                            $gender = $_POST['gender'];
                        
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM uc_messages WHERE CONCAT(firstname, lastname, message, date, email) LIKE ? AND gender = ?";
                        
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
                        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $search_values, $gender);                            
                        $stmt->execute();
                                                    
                        $result = $stmt->get_result();
                                                    
                        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

                          // output data of each row
                          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                            ?>
                                <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row['firstname'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['lastname'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['gender'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['message'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['date'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php

                          }
                        } 

                        $conn->close();

                    }

                ?>
```

And the final result if I search *test* and *MALE* :

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked brilliantly. Do you know how I would be able to make search work in conjunction with Gender sort? For example I would write Alex in search bar and Male for gender and that would bring up the records that fit that criteria? e.g. Alex Smith Male, Alexander Brad Male

Comment: It is already working with the source code I provide. Try to search Alex and Male or Paul and Female and it works. Otherwise, I didn't get the question 

Comment: And if you search for Alex and Female, you actually get no records. The AND operator in the SELECT statement make it works. You need both conditions to fit the request : the gender dropdown and the search text input.